# Check with regex if pattern matchs

Tags: python, regex

How can I check if a string matchs a pattern with regex:
I have to check if my input is:

**number comma number**

5, 7 : return true

a, 5: return false

5 7: return false

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and show your efforts.

Comment: which means try by yourself first

Answer (score 1):

`\d` in regex searches for a digit.

So your regular expression for (digit),(possible whitespace),(digit) becomes:
`re.match('[0-9],[ ]*[0-9]')` or `re.match('[\d],[ ]*[\d]')`

It'll search for:

- 5,5
- 5, 5
- 5,      5

If you want to omit the possibility of a space between comma and the second number, 
the regexp will be `re.match('[\d],[\d]')`